# Call a function on every request in vaadin 7

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm developing an Application with vaadin 7 in which I'd like to focus a textfield almost all the time. 
I now see two possibilities.

1. Find all possible actions (button clicks, table selects...) and call the focus function while handling this actions.
2. Find a way to call a method for every server round trip and only check if its one of the rare cases where the field should not be focused (mostly because a sub window was opened)

I'd prefer option 2, but haven't found out where I have to add some Listener/Handler or what function I have to override to call the focus function all the time.

Is option 2 possible? And if yes, how?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try using a BlurListener.

```
    final TextField tf = new TextField();
    layout.addComponent(tf);
    tf.focus();
    tf.addBlurListener(new FieldEvents.BlurListener() {
        @Override
        public void blur(FieldEvents.BlurEvent event) {
            if (fieldShouldBeFocused)
                tf.focus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I haven't thought of that. Good idea. Will try it soon and accept if it works.